# Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. C:\xampp\htdocs\phprojekt\library\Zend\Cache\Backend.php on line 66

Tags: php, xampp, each, deprecated

I'm a student at university.

And I have to install XAMPP, and then install a program called PHProjekt to use it with XAMPP.

Here is a quick video of the proccess of installing PHProjekt in order to use it with XAMPP.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfnGns5WiAY

When I get to the part where I have to login to PHProjekt I can't enter and get a message that says:

"Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in C:\xampp\htdocs\phprojekt\library\Zend\Cache\Backend.php on line 66"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAPs3.png)

Here is the code that the Backend.php document says:

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework
 *
 * LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
 * with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@zend.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Cache
 * @subpackage Zend_Cache_Backend
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2010 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 * @version    $Id: Backend.php 20882 2010-02-03 18:19:44Z matthew $
 */


/**
 * @package    Zend_Cache
 * @subpackage Zend_Cache_Backend
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2010 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class Zend_Cache_Backend
{
    /**
     * Frontend or Core directives
     *
     * =====> (int) lifetime :
     * - Cache lifetime (in seconds)
     * - If null, the cache is valid forever
     *
     * =====> (int) logging :
     * - if set to true, a logging is activated throw Zend_Log
     *
     * @var array directives
     */
    protected $_directives = array(
        'lifetime' => 3600,
        'logging'  => false,
        'logger'   => null
    );

    /**
     * Available options
     *
     * @var array available options
     */
    protected $_options = array();

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param  array $options Associative array of options
     * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
        while (list($name, $value) = each($options)) {
            $this->setOption($name, $value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the frontend directives
     *
     * @param  array $directives Assoc of directives
     * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDirectives($directives)
    {
        if (!is_array($directives)) Zend_Cache::throwException('Directives parameter must be an array');
        while (list($name, $value) = each($directives)) {
            if (!is_string($name)) {
                Zend_Cache::throwException("Incorrect option name : $name");
            }
            $name = strtolower($name);
            if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_directives)) {
                $this->_directives[$name] = $value;
            }

        }

        $this->_loggerSanity();
    }

    /**
     * Set an option
     *
     * @param  string $name
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function setOption($name, $value)
    {
        if (!is_string($name)) {
            Zend_Cache::throwException("Incorrect option name : $name");
        }
        $name = strtolower($name);
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_options)) {
            $this->_options[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the life time
     *
     * if $specificLifetime is not false, the given specific life time is used
     * else, the global lifetime is used
     *
     * @param  int $specificLifetime
     * @return int Cache life time
     */
    public function getLifetime($specificLifetime)
    {
        if ($specificLifetime === false) {
            return $this->_directives['lifetime'];
        }
        return $specificLifetime;
    }

    /**
     * Return true if the automatic cleaning is available for the backend
     *
     * DEPRECATED : use getCapabilities() instead
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAutomaticCleaningAvailable()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine system TMP directory and detect if we have read access
     *
     * inspired from Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Abstract
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception if unable to determine directory
     */
    public function getTmpDir()
    {
        $tmpdir = array();
        foreach (array($_ENV, $_SERVER) as $tab) {
            foreach (array('TMPDIR', 'TEMP', 'TMP', 'windir', 'SystemRoot') as $key) {
                if (isset($tab[$key])) {
                    if (($key == 'windir') or ($key == 'SystemRoot')) {
                        $dir = realpath($tab[$key] . '\\temp');
                    } else {
                        $dir = realpath($tab[$key]);
                    }
                    if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                        return $dir;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $upload = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
        if ($upload) {
            $dir = realpath($upload);
            if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                return $dir;
            }
        }
        if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {
            $dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
            if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                return $dir;
            }
        }
        // Attemp to detect by creating a temporary file
        $tempFile = tempnam(md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)), '');
        if ($tempFile) {
            $dir = realpath(dirname($tempFile));
            unlink($tempFile);
            if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir($dir)) {
                return $dir;
            }
        }
        if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('/tmp')) {
            return '/tmp';
        }
        if ($this->_isGoodTmpDir('\\temp')) {
            return '\\temp';
        }
        Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually');
    }

    /**
     * Verify if the given temporary directory is readable and writable
     *
     * @param $dir temporary directory
     * @return boolean true if the directory is ok
     */
    protected function _isGoodTmpDir($dir)
    {
        if (is_readable($dir)) {
            if (is_writable($dir)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Make sure if we enable logging that the Zend_Log class
     * is available.
     * Create a default log object if none is set.
     *
     * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _loggerSanity()
    {
        if (!isset($this->_directives['logging']) || !$this->_directives['logging']) {
            return;
        }

        if (isset($this->_directives['logger'])) {
            if ($this->_directives['logger'] instanceof Zend_Log) {
                return;
            }
            Zend_Cache::throwException('Logger object is not an instance of Zend_Log class.');
        }

        // Create a default logger to the standard output stream
        require_once 'Zend/Log.php';
        require_once 'Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php';
        $logger = new Zend_Log(new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('php://output'));
        $this->_directives['logger'] = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Log a message at the WARN (4) priority.
     *
     * @param  string $message
     * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _log($message, $priority = 4)
    {
        if (!$this->_directives['logging']) {
            return;
        }

        if (!isset($this->_directives['logger'])) {
            Zend_Cache::throwException('Logging is enabled but logger is not set.');
        }
        $logger = $this->_directives['logger'];
        if (!$logger instanceof Zend_Log) {
            Zend_Cache::throwException('Logger object is not an instance of Zend_Log class.');
        }
        $logger->log($message, $priority);
    }
}
```

The code in line 66 says: " while (list($name, $value) = each($options)) { "

It is in a function like this:

```
public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
        while (list($name, $value) = each($options)) {
            $this->setOption($name, $value);
        }
    }
```

Note: I'm a new student, studying php is not the focus of that class and I have not studied php, so I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: PHProjekt has not been touched in quite a while and appears to have been abandoned. It is expecting a much older version of PHP than you have installed, and is complaining about old PHP features that have been recently deprecated. If you fix this one issue, it is likely you will encounter may others. Your best bet is probably to use an older version of PHP.

Comment: Yes, it has more than one error, however, it was the same kind deprecated function on different places among the same document and in others, after using the solution gaven to me by Barmar on different places I was able to enter. Also thank you very much as well. I did see it had many errors, but at the end I was able to enter correcting what seemed to avoided me from doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($options as $name => $value) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked very well. I would upvote your answere, but I'm new here, so I don't have enough reputation for that.